# Matplotlib figure not responding when used with multiprocessing

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a very basic app that will update charts in matplotlib from a streaming data source. Data is received in a separate process. But my matplotlib figure keeps dying on me even for the most basic display. The matplotlib window looses interactivity and turns into **"Figure 1 (Not Responding)"**. Do I need to give matplotlib some CPU time explicitly in order to make it work nicely with `multiprocessing`?

Here is a basic sample that dies on pretty much all backends on Windows 7, 64Bit, Python 2.7.3 32Bit. I'm using unofficial binary of scipy-stack from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/):

EDIT: It also does not appear to be working on Ubuntu (32bit).

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Process

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def p1_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


def p2_func():
    plt.ion()
    plt.plot([1.6, 2.7])
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1_proc = Process(target=p1_func)
    p2_proc = Process(target=p2_func)

    p1_proc.start()
    p2_proc.start()

    p1_proc.join()
    p2_proc.join()
```

What am I doing wrong?

**How do you generally make a matplotlib interactive graphing of live data and threading (multiprocessing or otherwise) coexist?**

Comment: gui event loops and multi-process don't get along.  Either keep all the plotting in the main process or make use of the threading in what ever toolkit you are using (but again, keep all plotting on the main thread, just farm work out).

Comment: Any way to churn through gui event loop?

Comment: You might solve some issues by changing the backend http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here below a simple example

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DataStreamProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, connec, *args, **kwargs):
        self.connec = connec
        Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        random_gen = np.random.mtrand.RandomState(seed=127260)
        for _ in range(30):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            new_pt = random_gen.uniform(-1., 1., size=2)
            self.connec.send(new_pt)


def main():
    conn1, conn2  = Pipe()
    data_stream = DataStreamProcess(conn1)
    data_stream.start()

    plt.gca().set_xlim([-1, 1.])
    plt.gca().set_ylim([-1, 1.])
    plt.gca().set_title("Running...")
    plt.ion()

    pt = None
    while True:
        if not(conn2.poll(0.1)):
            if not(data_stream.is_alive()):
                break
            else:
                continue
        new_pt = conn2.recv()
        if pt is not None:
            plt.plot([pt[0], new_pt[0]], [pt[1], new_pt[1]], "bs:")
            plt.pause(0.001)
        pt = new_pt

    plt.gca().set_title("Terminated.")
    plt.draw()
    plt.show(block=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having problems using `matplotlib.animation` within a `multiprocessing.Pool` (the process would silently crash) and I was able to solve them by following the suggestion from @deinonychusaur, namely, use a non-interactive backend.

Add this to your imports:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('AGG')  # Do this BEFORE importing matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Read about backends here: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Answer (score 1):

You can also use threads instead, I used pylab for plotting.

```
import pylab
from threading import Thread


def threaded_function(arg):
    pylab.plot(range(1,10))
    pylab.show(block=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target = threaded_function, args = (10, ))
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    print("thread finished...exiting")
```

Answer (score 0):

`join()` waits unti the process completes. In this case, the code is waiting for an infinite loop :)

To build on @tcaswell's comment, mixing the GUI loop and the multiprocessing stuff is dicey.  Try this first, instead of the above join code:

```
   procs = [p1_proc, p2_proc]
   while any( (p.is_alive() for p in procs) ):
      time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Still the same (Not Responding). Is the real solution to embed matplotlib explicitly in the backend window where I can fully control gui event loop?